# Scheduler Module crontab job does not publish content

Tags: 8, cron

When running the Scheduler lightweight cron through crontab, I am getting a message that the lightweight cron has activated and completed in my D8 log, but content is not publishing. When running the lightweight cron through backoffice, items publish correctly. I've checked the cron log to see if the cron is encountering errors, and am seeing no issues. Is there something I am missing in my crontab command that is causing the cron to run but not update publish status on any of the scheduled nodes?

Comment: did you figure this out? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Content Access module, see that issue :
https://www.drupal.org/node/2865787

Enzo

Comment: why, and what does it say?